# a one-word adjective meaning "just a moment ago" or "just moments ago"

Tags: word-request

Is there any one-word adverb in English meaning "just a moment ago" or "just moments ago"? For example:

> The above section is for quick dashing off of names of folders or
>   files that have been modified **just moments ago**.

Comment: I know of no single word that unambiguously means "just moments ago". You are misusing the phrase **dash off**.

Comment: "You are misusing the phrase dash off" - How am I misusing it?

Comment: To **dash (something) off** is to produce in haste a note, a letter, a reply, etc for *someone else* to read. Unless I've misunderstood your scenario here, you yourself are the reader of this quick listing of file names.  We wouldn't say "Click this button to dash off a listing of recently modified files, so you can choose which one to edit."

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - Where did you get this "for someone else to read" from? Webster has this definition: "to write (something) in a very quick and hurried way", it doesn't narrow it down to "someone else to read".

Comment: I don't think that definition by Webster accurately and fully captures how the phrase is used.  We don't **dash things *off*** to *ourselves* as intended recipient.  It's missing the sense of **off**. As I said, we wouldn't dash off a listing to our desktop computer screen.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - Would you "dash off" some of your momentary thoughts on the paper to come back to them later?

Comment: I think it is highly unlikely that a native speaker (I'm one) would use **dash off** like this: "I dashed off his address so I wouldn't forget it."  The **off** conveys the idea of your hasty words being *sent* ,  or at least the idea that they are written with that intent. You might think better of it and tear the letter up.

Comment: It doesn't mean "to write something down quickly" but "to speak one's mind or to convey one's purpose or intention in writing in haste, often carelessly or without careful consideration"

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - What if I drop "off"? Can I just use "dashing" in the sense of writing something for myself?

Comment: No, **dash** isn't used like that.  We wouldn't say *I dashed it so I wouldn't forget it* or *I'm dashing it so I won't forget to do it.*   The dictionary definitions are very misleading. As I said, "to write in haste" tells only half of the story, and the half it leaves out is an *essential* piece.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - I just had a second thought: If "off" in "dashing off" is taken as implying "off my head" then everything seems to be consistent. Not?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "everything seems to be consistent".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - I mean consistent with the idea of hastily sending words, except not off to someone, but rather off your head onto the paper.

Comment: The verb is not used as you're using it.  That's what matters. You cannot *justify* the use by argument in which the verb is treated like a puzzle piece or machined part that fits into a certain shape or assembly.  Verbs have their meaning ONLY as a result of how they're actually used by speakers in the aggregate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do much better than 'recently', beyond that you get into multi-word territory with 'very recently' or 'moments ago' (since dropping the 'just' doesn't really affect the meaning).

Alternatively, I'd formulate it as:

> The above section is for quick dashing off of names of folders or files that have just been modified.

Comment: Do you think "freshly modified" could get the point across?

Comment: 'Freshly' sounds a bit odd when talking about files or folders, if you ask me (as a software engineer) - I'm not sure it would improve much on 'recently modified'. I also considered 'newly modified', but you end up with something feeling less recent than 'moments ago' in all cases. In technical parlance 'recently modified' is the most common and how recent is considered really recent, depends on context. 'Have just been modified' is the best I can do.